# How to change file extension in Linux shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

I've found some examples of doing this in similar situations, but this is the only shell-script I've written that does anything besides run commands verbatim, so I am struggling to apply the examples to my own situation and need some hand-holding <3

I'm just trying to batch rip audio from MP4s. This script works:

```
for f in *.mp4; 
    ffmpeg -i "$f" -f mp3 -ab 192000 -vn "mp3s/$f.mp3"
done
```

But the files all end with .mp4.mp3. How can I get rid of the mp4 part?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're using bash

```
${f%%.mp4}
```

will give the filename without the `.mp4` extension.

Try using it like this:

```
for f in *.mp4; do
    ffmpeg -i "$f" -f mp3 -ab 192000 -vn "mp3s/${f%%.mp4}.mp3"
done
```

... and don't forget the `do` keyword as in the example given.

### Explanation

The bash Manual(`man bash`) states:

> ${parameter%word} ${parameter%%word}
>
> Remove matching suffix pattern. 
>   The word is expanded to produce
>                 a pattern just as in pathname expansion.  If the pattern matches
>                 a trailing portion of the expanded value of parameter, then  the
>                 result  of the expansion is the expanded value of parameter with
>                 the shortest matching pattern (the `%'' case)  or  the  longest
>                 matching  pattern  (the`%%'' case) deleted.  If parameter is @
>                 or *, the pattern removal operation is  applied  to  each  positional  parameter  in  turn,  and the expansion is the resultant
>                 list.  If parameter is an array variable subscripted with  @  or
>                 *,  the  pattern  removal operation is applied to each member of
>                 the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.

This is just one of many string manipulations you can perform on shell variables. They all go by the name of **Parameter Expansion**.

That's as well the section label given in the bash manual. Thus `man bash` <kbd>/paramter exp</kbd> should bring you there fast.
`

Comment: This is exactly what I needed and it works great, thanks! If you wouldn't mind though could you describe briefly what ${f%%.mp4} means or what that sort of operation is called so I can look it up? Will accept answer as soon as it allows me to.

Comment: According to your feedback I added the explanation to my post. As I already stated there **Parameter Expansion** is the term you might want to lookup in the bash manual.

Answer (score 0):

Following command to change file extension for all files under the current directory.

```
find . -depth -name "*.c" -exec sh -c 'dname=$(dirname {}) && fname=$(basename {} .c) && mv {} $dname/$fname.h' ";"
```