# Bash: using {} to replace filename extension

Tags: bash, parameter-expansion

I'm testing out bash filename replacement with parameter expansion as shown here: [How to change file extension in Linux shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234593/how-to-change-file-extension-in-linux-shell-script#15234637)

However, I can't seem to get the following to work as I intend:

given the following files:

```
tmp/01. Losing A Whole Year.flac
tmp/02. Narcolepsy.flac
```

I run `find` for flac files into `parallel` running the `echo` command for testing output. I'm trying to replace `.flac` with `.mp3`.

```
find tmp -type f -name '*.flac' | time parallel -j+0 --eta 'echo "{} {.flac%%.mp3}"'
```

My output is:

```
tmp/01. Losing A Whole Year.flac {.flac%%.mp3}
tmp/02. Narcolepsy.flac {.flac%%.mp3}
```

I'm planning on using this with `ffmpeg` if that makes a difference.

Edit:
Expected output:

```
tmp/01. Losing A Whole Year.flac tmp/01. Losing A Whole Year.mp3
tmp/02. Narcolepsy.flac tmp/02. Narcolepsy.mp3
```

Edit 2:
To replace the file extension, I can use:

```
find tmp -type f -name '*.flac' | time parallel -j+0 --eta 'echo "{} {.flac%%.mp3}"'
```

However, this provides the following output

```
tmp/01. Losing A Whole Year.flac tmp/01.\ Losing\ A\ Whole\ Year.mp3
tmp/02. Narcolepsy.flac tmp/02.\ Narcolepsy.mp3
```

Maybe this is an ffmpeg question now, because ffmpeg will not be able to find the file if there's a `\` character in place of a space character.

Comment: Things are not working as expected because you are using Parallel substitutions, not Bash. Bash substitutions are prefixed with `$`.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out:

```
find tmp -type f -name '*.flac' | time parallel -j+0 --eta 'echo "{} {.}.mp3"'
```

will produce the expected results.

Although, I don't know why this doesn't work:

```
find tmp -type f -name '*.flac' | time parallel -j+0 --eta 'echo "{} {.flac}.mp3"'
```

Edit:
While the above seems to work, `\` characters are inserted to replace blank spaces, which would cause ffmpeg to not find the desired files.